# Installing cx_Oracle for Python on Linux Mint 16

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I've followed the directions here http://maxolasersquad.blogspot.com/2011/04/cxoracle-on-ubuntu-1104-natty.html to install cx_Oracle on my machine.

I've installed Oracle Client 11.2 and cx_Oracle 11g for Python 3.3, both 64 bit. cx_Oracle is listed as a module using `help('modules')`, however I'm getting the following error message on import:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle
ImportError: libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It would seem I'm missing a file, but I'm not sure if I need to install a dependency, or if some configuration is not setup correctly to point to the client.

Thanks for your assistance with this.

Edit:

Update, when I run `echo $ORACLE_HOME` and `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, I get the expected values now. However, the error still shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed the guide that you referenced, you've also created a script in `/etc/profile.d/`. Make sure that this script ends in `.sh`.

Your problem is probably related to loading the script from this directory, which I'm guessing is because you're running python from a *non-login* bash shell.

To verify that this is the case, try to invoke bash with `bash --login`, or do `source /etc/profile` in an existing bash shell. Then check if the variables `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` gets defined with a sensible value.

If that works, there are some relevant questions (and answers!) on scripts in `/etc/profile.d` at AskUbuntu that might be helpful:

- [/etc/profile not being sourced](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40287/etc-profile-not-being-sourced)
- [Scripts in /etc/profile.d Being Ignored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438150/scripts-in-etc-profile-d-being-ignored)

--

edit:

The environment variables are inherited – if the shell has a variable, then anything started from that shell should inherit those variables.

With this in mind, try to do:

```
$ bash --login
$ python
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ.get('ORACLE_HOME', '<not set>')
>>> print os.environ.get('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', '<not set>')
>>> import cx_Oracle
```

Comment: I followed your answer to double check, and I'm not getting the appropriate responses for both variables when I echo them. However, I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: You were right about the non-login bash shell bit! After running bash --login, then immediately hopping into python, everything works. I will look at the sources you posted to try and figure out how to best remedy this situation. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you export ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable?

I think LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not up.
If not set it in your environement:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

edit:

ok, what happen if you run just sqlplus?

Did you set NLS_LANG?

Try for example

```
export NLS_LANG=american_america.WE8ISO8859P1;
```

Comment: I have /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh with the lines:
    `export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64`
    `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib`
Would add it to my Path?

Comment: Check interactively if this variables is well defined

Comment: When I run `echo $ORACLE_HOME`, I get the expected path. When I run `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, I get a blank response.

Comment: I double checked based on fredrikhl's answer, and now I am getting the appropriate responses, but the same error.